# record column parameters all nil in database after adding record using admin panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

When adding a new record to a ruby on rails app via the admin panel everything seems fine. However in development, the record is not storing to the database correctly. I'm assuming this will happen in production too. When I view the record in the console all the column values are "nil" that are associated with the assets uploaded to amazon-s3 bucket (thumbnail_size, content_type etc...). The odd thing is the assets are displaying and look to be uploading correctly in the app. However, somehow the new record in the DB is not getting information back from s3? I checked the logs and I don't see any errors.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does the relevant code look like? What are you seeing in the logs after you execute the request?

Comment: Everything looks normal in the logs when I add a new record via the admin panel. Everything is working the record is added and viewable in the admin panel and on the site. However, for some bizarre reason, when I view the record in the console, those column values are nil. This causes issues b/c sorting and stuff looks at those values. I feel like it's an s3 issue because this just happened suddenly without changing any code.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code/screenshots/logs as well?

Comment: In the server log it just shows the record columns like this: 'thumbnail_file_name: nil, thumbnail_content_type: nil, thumbnail_file_size: nil, thumbnail_updated_at: nil, ' But it all uploads OK. Same on production. No idea why this happened all the sudden. My guess is something changed with the S3 amazon account. It seems the app isn't getting that info. Or maybe need to update some gem like paperclip. argh. Was hoping someone ran into the same problem.